# ValueError : Input 0 of layer sequential_13 is incompatible with the layer:

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence, perceptron

I faced the following problems in conducting artificial intelligence practice using Python. How do I solve this problem?
I want to recognize Cifar-10 data using MLP. However, an error occurs when you write as follows: What should I do to solve this problem?
Please help me.

I added an error to the body. I'd appreciate it if you could help me.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D,Flatten,Dense,Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

# CIFAR-10 데이터셋을 읽고 신경망에 입력할 형태로 변환
(x_train,y_train),(x_test,y_test)=cifar10.load_data()
x_train=x_train.astype(np.float32)/255.0
x_test=x_test.astype(np.float32)/255.0
y_train=tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train,10)
y_test=tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test,10)

n_input=1024
n_hidden=1024
n_output=10

# 신경망 모델 설계
mlp=Sequential()
mlp.add(Dense(units=n_hidden,activation='tanh',input_shape=(n_input,),kernel_initializer='random_uniform',bias_initializer='zeros'))
mlp.add(Dense(units=n_output,activation='tanh',kernel_initializer='random_uniform',bias_initializer='zeros'))

# 신경망 모델 학습
mlp.compile(optimizer=Adam(),metrics=['accuracy'])
hist=mlp.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=30, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), verbose=2)

# 신경망 모델 정확률 평가
res=mlp.evaluate(x_test,y_test,verbose=0)
print("정확률은",res[1]*100)
```

Error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    984           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    985             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 986               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    987             else:
    988               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:855 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:845 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1285 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2833 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3608 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:838 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1013 __call__
        input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:255 assert_input_compatibility
        ' but received input with shape ' + display_shape(x.shape))

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_13 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1024 but received input with shape (None, 32, 32, 3)
```

Comment: Which line raise this error?

Comment: @Kaveh I added an error to the body. I'd appreciate it if you could help me.

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues in your code. I modified them and pasted whole code. I have added descriptions as comments. However there are more advices for your model to get a good accuracy.

I list more important issues in your code:

- You should have an input layer to define your input tensor and it's shape which is (32,32,3) for cifar10 dataset.
- Because your input is an image and is not a 1d array, you should add a flatten layer before feeding it to dense layers.
- Do not use `tanh` activation function for the last layer, because you want the output results [0,1], and tanh gives values [-1,1].
- You had not used loss function in the `model.compile()` method. I have added for you.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D,Flatten,Dense,Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

# CIFAR-10 데이터셋을 읽고 신경망에 입력할 형태로 변환
(x_train,y_train),(x_test,y_test)=cifar10.load_data()
x_train=x_train.astype(np.float32)/255.0
x_test=x_test.astype(np.float32)/255.0
y_train=tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train,10)
y_test=tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test,10)

n_input=1024
n_hidden=1024
n_output=10

# 신경망 모델 설계
mlp=Sequential()
mlp.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(32,32,3))) #add input layer and specify input shape
mlp.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())   #flatten your layer, since your input is a 3d (WHC) data
mlp.add(Dense(units=n_hidden,activation='tanh',kernel_initializer='random_uniform',bias_initializer='zeros')) #remove input_shape, since you don't need it
mlp.add(Dense(units=n_output,activation='softmax',kernel_initializer='random_uniform',bias_initializer='zeros')) #tanh is not a good activation since you want values between 0,1 as output

# 신경망 모델 학습
mlp.compile(optimizer=Adam(),metrics=['accuracy'], loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy) #add loss function
hist=mlp.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=30, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), verbose=2)

# 신경망 모델 정확률 평가
res=mlp.evaluate(x_test,y_test,verbose=0)
print("정확률은",res[1]*100)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# 정확률 그래프
plt.plot(hist.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(hist.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('Model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train','Validation'], loc='best')
plt.grid()
plt.show()

# 손실 함수 그래프
plt.plot(hist.history['loss'])
plt.plot(hist.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('Model loss')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train','Validation'],loc='best')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

UPDATE: For splitting train dataset to train and validation use code like this:

```
split_percent = 0.2         #exclude 20% for validation
split_index = int(x_train.shape[0]*(1-split_percent))
x_t = x_train[:split_index]  #x_train
y_t = y_train[:split_index]  #y_train
x_v = x_train[split_index:]  #x_val
y_v = y_train[split_index:]  #y_val
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know how long it took to solve this problem. Are you a coding genius? Thank you so much. I have one more question, how can I set 20% of the train data to validation set and use only test data for performance evaluation?

Comment: I have added the code for splitting dataset to my answer.